# How to change shutdown/Suspend/ off the main panel in Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome-panel, ubuntu-mate, dconf, administration

I want to log off and then shut-down my computer and those buttons are deprecated for me, I would like to change that Power button for log-out instead and the menu items too.

How can I achieve this ?, I'm at DConf

[image: DConf editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much simpler way to achieve a logout button in Ubuntu Mate.

Simply Right click the main panel and select add to panel. Type log in the box and select Logout. This will add a logout button to the panel.

If you so desire you can remove the shutdown button by right clicking it and choosing remove from panel.

Comment: I cannot set it to the same place but I can delete the power button

Comment: That's correct. While most of the items on the panel can be unlocked from the panel and moved at will, I've not found a way to move the Bluetooth and Network items, so it's as far as I know not possible to keep that order. Since all of these options are available on the Mate System Menu, it seems an unnecessary task